# Curl only connects to localhost regarding of where i am connecting. RCA might be VPN

Tags: security, vpn, curl

So, weirdly curl only connects to 'localhost' even if I am connecting to a different host.

```
curl -v https://registry.npmjs.org/
 *   Trying 104.16.22.35...
 * TCP_NODELAY set
 * Connected to registry.npmjs.org (127.0.0.1) port 443 (#0)
```

Thus cannot curl to anything.

It's happening after I stop my VPN connection. I believe it will happen to all terminal apps which requests for external sources.

With VPN everything works fine. Maybe it's a security feature?

Answer (score 0):

Check your shell environment. `HTTPS_PROXY=localhost` is a likely suspect, or `ALL_PROXY`. See the Environment section of [man curl](https://linux.die.net/man/1/curl).

Another possibility is `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, which may point to some of your VPN's libraries that intercept network calls in order to route them through the VPN.

Comment: hey thanks for the response. I had unset https_proxy and http_proxy. forgot to check all_proxy. And will try to check ld_library_path as well.

Comment: Update: no http proxy, https proxy, all_proxy. ld_library_path is at oracle instantclient(not vpn related).